# Eventlogging for IIS-Dotnet-Applicaiton without touching web.config-files

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis

I'm running an dotnet application, that is provided by a third party. In fact there is more than one server component with a few `web.config` files and sub-`web.config` files.
I don't want to touch any of the files of the installation, to ensure that any configuration-changes will not be forgotten in future upgrades or other stages.

I would like to enable a generic logging, to be able to react in cases of ysod-errors (like corrupted config files). Coming from the java-world I would expect, that IIS like maybe a tomcat writes it's unhandled exceptions into a simple log file, but that seems not to the case.

In the end I found a [solution](https://lowleveldesign.org/2012/07/11/asp-net-health-monitoring/) by adding

```
    <healthMonitoring>
      <eventMappings>
        <add name="All Errors" type="System.Web.Management.WebBaseErrorEvent,System.Web,Version=4.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" startEventCode="0" endEventCode="2147483647" />
      </eventMappings>
      <rules>
        <add name="All Errors Default" eventName="All Errors" provider="EventLogProvider" profile="Default" minInstances="1" maxLimit="Infinite" minInterval="00:01:00" custom="" />
        <add name="Failure Audits Default" eventName="Failure Audits" provider="EventLogProvider" profile="Default" minInstances="1" maxLimit="Infinite" minInterval="00:01:00" custom="" />
      </rules>
    </healthMonitoring>
```

to one of the `web.config`-files and force the application to fail at startup with an exception and now I can see the error within the event monitor, what is a cool progress compared to the error messages on the ysod till that configuration

```
<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->
(...)
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
(...)
```

But, I wonder, if I really have to touch a `web.config` file to enable something very basic like logging out the stack trace of an uncaught exception.
That doesn't feel right.
Is there a way to reach the logging of such error in a more generic way?

**Edit** after Albert D. Kallal's answer:
To be more precisely: I don't want to touch any files of the application(s), I expect a generic configuration on a higher level than the applocation.

Comment: Did you check Error logs of IIS in Event Viewer ?

Comment: I just can find IIS-CentralCertificateProvider, IIS-Configuration and IIS-Logging in the event viewer. There are no entries in any of them. do you know any other place I could have a look at?

Comment: In the Event Viewer -> Windows Logs -> Application you can find some logs that are coming from iis.

Comment: nope, can't find any logs with any exceptions from the application there.

Comment: you could try to Setup this event handler at the start of your application. In Program.cs, Startup.cs or your Global.asax file.

`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException += (sender, eventArgs) =>
{
 Debug.WriteLine(eventArgs.Exception.ToString());
};` or Open the IIS metabase which is located at 'C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv` Check in the IIS metabase for AspErrorsToNTLog and set to TRUE and save.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/6.0-sdk/ms524984(v=vs.90)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can get/grab/trap any system wide un-handled error.

There should be a page in the project called Global.asax.

It is in effect a code module without a web page.

And in that module, you have:

[image]

so you have applicaton start (code runs on startup).
You have session end - code runs on user session end

And you have that system wide error trap. So you can add code to that stub, and not have to touch or change the web.config files/settings for this to work.

And to get "much" the same as what asp.net spits out to the web page?

I don't have c#, but this will output quite much what you need. I have it send me a email, but you could write to a log, or whatever.

eg:
If (TypeOf Server.GetLastError() Is HttpUnhandledException) Then
ex = HttpContext.Current.Server.GetLastError().InnerException
Else
ex = HttpContext.Current.Server.GetLastError
End If

```
        Dim s As String = "Session Vars  (" & Session.Contents.Count.ToString & ")<br/><hr>"
        For i = 0 To Session.Contents.Count - 1
            Dim sKey As String
            sKey = Session.Keys(i)
            s += sKey & "---->" & Session(sKey).ToString & "<br/>"
        Next
        s += "<br/><hr>"
        WebNotice.AddField("Session", s)   ' my custom email web send class

        Dim s2 As String = ""
        Dim ex2 As Exception
        ex2 = ex.GetBaseException
        Do While IsNothing(ex2) = False
            s2 += "<br/>---" & ex2.StackTrace
            ex2 = ex2.InnerException
        Loop
        WebNotice.AddField("StackTrace", s2)
        s = ""
        If IsNothing(Server.GetLastError) = False Then
            s = Server.GetLastError().Message & "<br/>"
            s += Server.GetLastError().StackTrace & "<br/>"
            s += Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException.Message & "<br/>"
            s += Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException.StackTrace & "<br/>"

        End If
        WebNotice.AddField("MoreInfo", s)

        'Debug.Print(ex.InnerException.Message)
        ' try to get logged on user  (often error could be due to timeout)
        Try
            uid = Membership.GetUser.ProviderUserKey
        Catch
        End Try
        WebNotice.DataPK = uid

        Server.ClearError()

        WebNotice.SendNotice("CodeError")
```

So the above sends me a email. I also list out current session() values, the logged in user (or if they are not logged in etc.).

So, you can global trap errors. In fact, during development/debug? I put in a exit sub on the first line - don't want/need emails during debug and dev process. But the above quite much outputs a similar message as the stack trace etc. And it nice since i get a email when the web site has a code error.

You don't' have to use or follow the above code idea, but the basic concept here is that you do have a global error trap in

```
Sub Application_Error(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
```

so above code is called on that error. From that you can loop the error object, and write to a log file or even send a email. As noted, I also write out the session() values as that tends to help track down the error. I also grab the current URL, as again that tells me where the user was.

There are as many flavors of ice cream as to what you log or write out. but the basic concept is that global error code sub runs, and you can add this to your application without having to change the web configs and settings for this to work.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, i will give it a try to have a further workaround, because I still believe that there must be a more generic solution. The situation keeps unchanged: An uncaught error is detected by the components and displayed as ysod, but at the moment it is not logged out at server side, which still doesn't feel fine. I updated the question to take your proposition into account .